# fiware install spagobi on ubuntu server 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, spagobi

trying to install spagobi on ubuntu 16.04 server, with:

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SpagoBILabs/SpagoBI/master/ChefCookbooks/installation.sh 
| ssh -i <identity file> <sudo user>@<ip of machine>
```

in mysql step, i have:

```
================================================================================
Error executing action `create` on resource 'mysql_service[default1]'
================================================================================

NoMethodError
-------------
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Cookbook Trace:
---------------
/home/jakala/.chef/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/mysql/libraries/helpers.rb:284:in `package_name_for'
/home/jakala/.chef/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/mysql/libraries/helpers.rb:325:in `server_package'
/home/jakala/.chef/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/mysql/libraries/helpers.rb:336:in `server_package_name'
/home/jakala/.chef/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/mysql/libraries/provider_mysql_service.rb:30:in `block in <class:MysqlService>'
Resource Declaration:
---------------------
# In /home/jakala/.chef/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/spagobi/recipes/1.0.2_install.rb

 76: mysql_service 'default1' do
 77:   version '5.5'
 78:   bind_address '0.0.0.0'
 79:   port '3306'
 80:   initial_root_password 'root'
 81:   action [:create, :start]
 82: end
 83: 

Compiled Resource:
------------------
# Declared in /home/jakala/.chef/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/spagobi/recipes/1.0.2_install.rb:76:in `from_file'

mysql_service("default1") do
  action [:create, :start]
  retries 0
  retry_delay 2
  default_guard_interpreter :default
  declared_type :mysql_service
  cookbook_name "spagobi"
  recipe_name "1.0.2_install"
  version "5.5"
  bind_address "0.0.0.0"
  port "3306"
  initial_root_password "root"
end


 Running handlers: [2016-06-16T06:49:41+00:00] ERROR: Running exception
 handlers Running handlers complete [2016-06-16T06:49:41+00:00] ERROR:
 Exception handlers complete Chef Client failed. 3 resources updated in
 11 seconds [2016-06-16T06:49:41+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to
 /home/jakala/.chef/local-mode-cache/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
 [2016-06-16T06:49:41+00:00] ERROR: mysql_service[default1]
 (spagobi::1.0.2_install line 76) had an error: NoMethodError:
 undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass [2016-06-16T06:49:42+00:00]
 FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited
unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

I think its because ubuntu 16.04 does not have mysql5.5 (as in file .chef/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/spagobi/recipes/1.0.2_install.rb says in lines 76-80):

```
mysql_service 'default1' do
  version '5.5'
  bind_address '0.0.0.0'
  port '3306'
  initial_root_password 'root'
  action [:create, :start]
end
```

I try to change this file but command:

```
sudo chef-client -z -o 'recipe[spagobi::1.0.2_install]'
```

rebokes my changes. I also try to add mysql-server5.5 repository adding:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ondrej/mysql-5.5
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

but the same error persists.

Anyone can help me?  How to install spagobi in ubuntu server 16.04?

Answer (score 0):

since that Chef recipe was developed considering mysql 5.5, I suggest you to use another recipe, the one for SpagoBI demo (using HSQLDB files databases):

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SpagoBILabs/SpagoBI/master/ChefCookbooks/installation.sh | ssh -i <identity file> <sudo user>@<ip of machine> 'bash /dev/stdin demo'
```

Then you can modify that SpagoBI instance and change data sources. See http://spagobi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/admin/README/index.html#installation for details.

Hope this helps

Davide